# WCF service crashing, no log no hints, way to get them

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a problem with a WCF service. It works ok for a while and suddenly and randomly it just closes and terminates. Nothing appears in the log. I checked even system logs. Nothing. It just says it terminates. I added trace logging but still nothing appears in the logs.

I added this lines to get some hints but nothing valuable appears there.

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="messages"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
      initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Error, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="traceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "c:\logs\traces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <source name="UserTraceSource" switchValue="Error, ActivityTracing" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml"
         type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
         initializeData="C:\logs\UserTraces.svclog" />
    </listeners>
  </source>

</sources>
```

Also I have all functions wrapped in try/catch blocks with breakpoints in Visual Studio in the except part and never reaches there. I am looking for some hints on how to solve the situation to locate the possible faulting code.

Edit: I am hosting in IIS.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Common Language Runtime exception breaking? It's possible that it is throwing an exception elsewhere in your application that you don't have covered with a `try/catch` block. By enabling this it should break and show you the line that caused the exception when one is encountered.

Comment: How are you hosting your service? IIS?

Comment: Yes I am hosting in IIS

Comment: Stephen I tried that but it breaks way too much. Sometimes it can't delete files from temp folder and such, so it breaks even when handled if I enable that. It just doesn't break only on unhandled exception as program normally would so Microsoft made it a pain because of that. Just service terminated. No logs no nothing. It happens randomly. Sometimes works great for days and then kaboom.